# mix-blend-mode not displaying text over the gradient

Tags: css, material-ui

I want to display some text over my gradient background. When I do it normally, just putting MUI's `Typography` or a simple `<p>`, it works. But the text is black, it doesn't have the best contrast.

I learned that I can use something like `mix-blend-mode` to somehow set the contrast according to the background, so I decided to use it.

This is how my div looks like:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => {
  const fontSize = 15;

  return createStyles({
    avatarText: {
      mixBlendMode: "difference",
    },
  });
});

<div className="profile-basic-info">
  <Avatar src={avatar} className="avatar" />
  <Typography variant="h3" className={classes.avatarText}>
    {firstName} {lastName}
  </Typography>
  <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.avatarText}>
    {email}
  </Typography>
</div>
```

This is the css (SCSS actually) for this div:

```
.profile-basic-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 500px;

  border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
  padding: $padding;

  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);

  .avatar {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 360px !important;
    height: 360px !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
}
```

So I use `classes.avatarText` to style the `Typography` (this is just a MUI quirk, works the same as styling in plain css).

The problem here is, after adding the `mix-blend-mode`, the text disappears, look:

[image]

When I just comment out the `background: [...]` (gradient) in my css, the text of course is displayed:

[image]

Is there something I am doing wrong here?

P.S It's not some MUI bug, I also checked it with `<p>` and specifying the `mix-blend-mode` in CSS file (and inline for that matter) - still the text is hidden under the gradient (or not displayed?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default color of the font is black. Black is hex 000000 so if you difference any other color with it you get that color - hence the font seems to disappear.

Try making the font color white. Then the difference will show up.

Here's a simplified version of your code showing that:

```css
.avatartext {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  color: white;
}

.profile-basic-info {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-basic-info">
  <div class="avatartext">John Smith</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works! The contrast is good, just the picked color isn't the best though, but nothing I can do about it I guess: https://imgur.com/a/JtZOVKJ. It also depends on the color I choose - different color when I choose a color like `brown`

Comment: Yes, I find you have to play around with colors to get something you want - I never manage to plan it in advance using the formula.